# Javascript issue, dont know when it changes state

Tags: javascript

http://jsfiddle.net/fqwvy/12/

I want to "Color" the feilds inbetween "From" and "To", i managed to get it to color the picked feild, but i really dont know how to aproach this.

I also want to reset the css color, when something else is picked, is there an easy way to do this?

Any suggestions are welcome :)

```
 fiddle_requires_some_code_to_post();
```

Comment: *`fiddle_requires_some_code_to_post();`* [`Indeed_that_s_because_we_would_prefer_you_to_post_your_code_in_the_question_itself();`](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149890/prevent-posts-with-links-to-jsfiddle-and-no-code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to loop through your `<tds>` between your "from" and "to" and set them. You have both the ids already, so it's pretty straightforward. You'll want to make sure your "to" index is set to your "from" index if nothing is selected.

**Demo:** <sub><sub><sub>[image: jsFiddle]</sub></sub></sub>

```js
evT = end_time[to_color.value] ? end_time[to_color.value] : evF;

for( var index = evF - 1; index < evT; index++ ) {
    $("#color"+(index+1)).css("background-color","red"); 
};
```

To clear all the colors you can do something like this, which says "all the `<tds>` with `id` starting with `color`":

```js
$( 'td[id^="color"]' ).css( "background-color", "" );
```

Comment: As for the reset of the colors when something else is picked, do you think inserting:

    $( "#color"+( index + 1 ) ).css( "background-color","none" ); 

and looping true all, would be the best aproach?

Comment: yes, I mention that. You should clear them out. See above code.

Comment: @JohnDoe You can clear them all at once. I edit my answer with a sample.

Comment: accepted, as a last note, do you have any suggestion on how to make "mark" the colors even if the "from" crosses 23? (on jsfiddle i made it 4)

as in, selected = from 10 to 8

the markup would hit 11-12-13-14-15-16-17-18-19-20-21-22-23-00-01-etc up to 08

Comment: @JohnDoe That's quite a bit more difficult. It might be best to start a new question for that since it's a different issue. You might want to use your real values (is it times?) instead of numbers so it will be clearer what your looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines of:

```
        if(evF < evT){
            for(i=evF + 1; i < evT; i++){
              $("#color"+ i).css("background-color","red");
            }
         }
```

Then you will have an *else if* statement and do the reverse of when evT is greater than evF.

Also, I didn't see any code that cleared out the background color of red on subsequent selections. That would be good to add.